# Getting relationship fault while accessing a child object in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a two core data entities `Contact` and `Group`. Groups have two attributes `existingUsers` and `nonExistingUsers` which are of type `Contact` and toMany relationship

I'm trying to fetch group attributes using `groupId` as a predicate. This is how I'm fetching group details

```
let requestForGroups = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Group")
    requestForGroups.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    requestForGroups.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "groupId == %@", (groupObject?.groupId)!)
    requestForGroups.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = ["existingUsers", "nonExistingUsers"]
    do {
        let results = try managedObjectContext.fetch(requestForGroups) as! [Group]
        if results.count > 0 {
            print(results.first)
            var group: Group!
            group = results.first
            for users in group.existingUsers?.allObjects as! [Contact] {
                print(users)
            }
            for users in group.nonExistingUsers?.allObjects as! [Contact] {
                print(users)
            }
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error: \(error) " +
            "description \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

When I try to print the `Group` object, I get the following relationship fault

```
Optional(<Foodvite.Group: 0x1706801e0> (entity: Group; id: 0xd0000000018c0000 <x-coredata://E4C6CB69-7192-435C-9E2A-534FCFC563F5/Group/p99> ; data: {
existingUsers = "<relationship fault: 0x17063b620 'existingUsers'>";
groupCategory = nil;
groupIconUrl = nil;
groupId = "8ba3e576-edf7-41fa-abd9-df80c4c693f2";
groupName = Friends;
groupOwnerId = "7fa49a4e-2cbf-4c77-8868-bc97ad89881b";
nonExistingUsers = "<relationship fault: 0x17063b600 'nonExistingUsers'>";
}))
```

Can someone suggest a way to access `existingUsers` and `nonExistingUsers` data?

Comment: Try something like `print(existingUsers!.first?.<#some property#>)`

Comment: `existingUsers` is of type `NSSet`. It doesn't have `first` property

Comment: fair point, but there's the `allObjects` property of NSSet that returns Array

Answer (score 1):

This is correct as Coredata relationships are loaded lazily by default.

Here is Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html) on the same.

> Managed objects typically represent data held in a persistent store.
>   In some situations a managed object may be a fault—an object whose
>   property values have not yet been loaded from the external data store.
>   Faulting reduces the amount of memory your application consumes.

To access `existingUsers` and `nonExistingUsers` data, you need to explicitly ask(if they are not arrays):

```
print(group!.existingUsers.<attributeName>)
print(group!.nonExistingUsers.<attributeName>)
```

If your relationships are arrays:

```
if let first = group?.existingUsers.first {
    print(first.<attributeName>)
}
```

Read [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-a-core-data-fault--cms-25157) for better understanding.

Comment: I'm still getting the same fault error. Can you suggest another way to access the data?

Comment: @Aark: When do you get the fault error? While in debug mode in console?  Or in print(results.first)?

Comment: I'm getting the fault error for `Print(results.first)` as well as `Print(group!.existingUsers)`. This is what was displayed in the console when tried printing `group.existingUsers` Optional(Relationship 'existingUsers' fault on managed object (0x17068e060) <Foodvite.Group: 0x17068e060> (entity: Group; id: 0xd000000001f00000 <x-coredata://E4C6CB69-7192-435C-9E2A-534FCFC563F5/Group/p124> ; data: {
    existingUsers = "<relationship fault: 0x17062ee60 'existingUsers'>";

Comment: Try fetching an attribute of existingUsers, if its an array you may need to access its element first. I am editing my answer..

Comment: `existingUsers` is of type `NSSet`. It doesn't have `first` property

Comment: Use anyObject().

Comment: It's giving nil :(

Answer (score 1):

A fault is not an error.  It is a performance consideration where data from the persistent store is not loaded unless you actually need it.  This is especially true for a fetched object that has a property that represents a to-many relationship to potentially *thousands* of other entities.  It would be silly to load thousands of other objects in memory if you aren't even going to use them.

In your case, `existingUsers` and `nonExistingUsers` are probably both NSSets.  You can access the elements within them like so:

```
//assuming "group" is an NSManagedObject

for user in group.existingUsers! {
    user.property = someValue
    if user.otherProperty == ...
}
```

Upon accessing each `user` in the set of `existingUsers`, the NSManagedObjectContext will automatically populate the object's properties with the values retrieved from the persistent store.  In short, the expected values for the properties of each `user` will properly be returned/set when you access or assign them.